# Trying to make a list keep getting TypeError: unorderable types: list() <= int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write a code that allows the user to fill an empty list with house prices then             sort them out by giving a a new value.

```
import Utils2

do_again = 'yes'

house_price = []

while do_again == 'yes' :
    price =Utils2.get_int('Please enter house price:')
    house_price.append(price)
    do_again = Utils2.yes_or_no('try another (yes or no)?')
#end while
mid_range_house = []
low_price_house =[]
high_price_house=[]

print('the price of houses is :')
for each in house_price:
    if (mid_range_house <=each ):
        low_price_house.append(each)
    else:
        high_price_house.append(each)
```

Comment: As Martijn said in his answer, it isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. What do you want your code to do?

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing a list with an integer:

```
if (mid_range_house <=each ):
```

where `mid_range_house` is the list, `each` is the integer.

It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve with your code, but you need to compare numbers with other numbers *only*.

If you wanted to find the median house price, sort your `house_price` list and pick the middle value:

```
median = sorted(house_price)[len(house_price) // 2]
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't very clear. I'm trying to write a code that will prompt the user to enter the price of different houses. Once all the desired prices have been added I want it to ask the user for a value that will sort out the previous values based o size. For example If I were to add 1,2,3,and 4. The user would put 3 and the values 3 and 4 would be returned. The code I have written is longer than the one posted but, this is the part where I have an issue.

Comment: In such case you should set `mid_range_house` to that user-entered integer then.